# Is Kotlin's range checking is efficent?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin

```
val x = 50000
if (x in 1..100000) {
    println(x)
}
```

I think the above code readability is better than code with inequality.
But I wonder the performence of that code is also good.

If it literally iterate 100000 times, it seems too stupid.

Is it equal to (1 <= x && x <= 100000) for performance?

Comment: Why you don't just benchmark it?

Comment: @MartinZeitler oh! I missed that idea. Thanks. I will do benchmark when facing similar question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `..` operator calls the [`rangeTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/range-to.html) operator function, which creates a `IntRange` object. The `in` operator then calls the [`contains`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/contains.html) operator function, which is [implemented](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/34e57a45f2d4283be572137b4b497414b8833ee7/core/builtins/src/kotlin/Range.kt#L12) as:

```
public operator fun contains(value: T): Boolean = value >= start && value <= endInclusive
```

Therefore, it does not loop 100000 times, and it is the same as

```
1 <= x && x <= 100000
```

except that it also creates a new `IntRange` object, which won't really matter in the grand scheme of things.